# Magento Collection Filtering functions

Tags: php, mysql, magento

What is the difference between addAttributeToFilter() and addFieldToFilter() when dealing with Magento collections? Does it have anything to do with whether or not the value is an eav_attribute?

EDIT: According to http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/catalog/using_collections_in_magento:

> addFieldToFilter($attribute, $condition=null) **-- alias for addAttributeToFilter()**

Can anybody confirm this?

Comment: Please see @Alan Storm comment
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1332742/magento-retrieve-products-with-a-specific-attribute-value

Comment: Thanks Vern, but I don't know that my specific question was addressed in that post.

Comment: The functionality basically is the same.  They add a WHERE CLAUSE to the query.  You just have to be very careful in which you use as some non-EAV tables have their own instances of addAttributeToFilter.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Apologies, there's no short answer that doesn't mislead or confuse things here.

Important Point #1: The Magento core team is loath to remove or rename methods from the source tree.  Startup culture meant they eschewed tests plus being a public project it meant they couldn't control what people did with their product.  Rather than remove methods and risk breaking things, they'll leave methods in place that call the new method.  This way, even if there's old code out there that calls the method, they're covered.

Important Point #2: The collection inheritance chain is screwy, and has been inconsistently applied in certain parts of the codebase.  This is being cleaned up, but it can still easily throw you for a loop.

Important Point #3: I'm speculating on how a lot of this is meant to be used and happened.  I am not the final authority here, I'm just someone trying to make sense of it. The specifics below refer to 1.6, but the concepts apply to all versions

All collections inherit from the class `Varien_Data_Collection_Db`. This is the class that models the basic concept of "collecting a series of objects loaded from the database".  This class has a single method `addFieldToFilter`.

```
public function addFieldToFilter($field, $condition=null)
{
    $field = $this->_getMappedField($field);
    $this->_select->where($this->_getConditionSql($field, $condition), null, Varien_Db_Select::TYPE_CONDITION);
    return $this;
}
```

which is a simple implementation that adds a where clause to the theoretical query.

Next up, there are **two** abstract classes that have `Varien_Data_Collection_Db` as an ancestor.  `Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract` and `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract`.

`Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract` is the collection class for "regular, non EAV models".  It has neither a `addFieldToFilter` method or an `addAttributeToFilter` method. It relies on the implementation in  on the base `Varien_Data_Collection_Db` class.

`Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract` is the collection class for EAV models.  It has an `addAttributeToFilter` method, which is more complex.

```
public function addAttributeToFilter($attribute, $condition = null, $joinType = 'inner')
{
    if ($attribute === null) {
        $this->getSelect();
        return $this;
    }

    if (is_numeric($attribute)) {
        $attribute = $this->getEntity()->getAttribute($attribute)->getAttributeCode();
    } else if ($attribute instanceof Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Interface) {
        $attribute = $attribute->getAttributeCode();
    }

    if (is_array($attribute)) {
        $sqlArr = array();
        foreach ($attribute as $condition) {
            $sqlArr[] = $this->_getAttributeConditionSql($condition['attribute'], $condition, $joinType);
        }
        $conditionSql = '('.implode(') OR (', $sqlArr).')';
    } else if (is_string($attribute)) {
        if ($condition === null) {
            $condition = '';
        }
        $conditionSql = $this->_getAttributeConditionSql($attribute, $condition, $joinType);
    }

    if (!empty($conditionSql)) {
        $this->getSelect()->where($conditionSql, null, Varien_Db_Select::TYPE_CONDITION);
    } else {
        Mage::throwException('Invalid attribute identifier for filter ('.get_class($attribute).')');
    }

    return $this;
}
```

That's because an attribute query is **not** a straight "where" query.  Also, this method was designed to take either an attribute name, **or** an attribute database ID, **or** an instantiated attribute object.  You are **not** adding a field to the filter, you're adding an attribute to the filter.  So, depending on the implementation of EAV and which table the attribute is stored in, you need to add a different bit of SQL code (a straight where query on the main table, a where added with one of the join tables, etc.)

This creates a problem.  Because this EAV collection object inherits from the base collection object, the `addFieldToFilter` still exists, and would still add a basic where condition to the EAV query, which might confuse an end user by not doing what they thought.  Therefore, the EAV collection class also has this

```
public function addFieldToFilter($attribute, $condition = null)
{
    return $this->addAttributeToFilter($attribute, $condition);
}
```

which wraps any call to `addFieldToFilter` to `addAttributeToFilter` (again, on an EAV model).  So, if you have an EAV model, you can use `addFieldToFilter` or `addAttributeToFilter`.  If you're working with a regular model, you may **only** call `addFieldToFilter`, `addAttributeToFilter` doesn't exist.

Ideally, the method names would have been unified from the start, but once the split happened, the Magento team chose to continue supporting the split in favor of backwards compatibility.

### Wait, There's More

There's two collections left in the codebase that inherit **directly** from Varien_Data_Collection_Db.  These are `Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Sale_Collection` and `Mage_Review_Model_Resource_Review_Summary_Collection`.  This number is higher in versions of Magento CE prior to 1.6.  While this doesn't impact the question of filtering, it does confuse the inheritance chain, so you should watch out for it.

Many non-EAV collections will implement their own `addFieldToFilter` to do sanity checks on variables, or jigger the query paramaters a little if they're doing something a little non standard.

The EAV collections get in on this act as well by redefining `addAttributeToFilter`.  Again, this is done to add custom logic that doesn't fit in with the basic Magento collection loading.