# How to filter by attribute on Magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I've been looking for a solution for this question. I found some information, but I don't know the exact steps for programming it.

I've created  attributes: hidraulics, electrics, battery, lamps. These attributes have also other extra attributes inside, and more than one category can have products from each attribute.

What I need is filter **by attribute**. If I click on a button I created, I need to filter by these four attributes (not the categories).

I've seen solutions, but I can't understand them. I would really appreciate some help on a specific instructions.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm getting what you want to do it should work by default when you go to the attribute settings and set "Use In Layered Navigation" to "filterable"?

Comment: Yes, but I want to make my own links on the page, so I need the code to load a page with a filtered attribute.

Comment: You'll have to filter by attribute on the product collection (ref: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1332742/magento-retrieve-products-with-a-specific-attribute-value). Hope you can take it from there :-)

Comment: Thanks! Couldn't find that!