# Listing products with a specific attribute in a category

Tags: magento

I have a category called "What's New" in Magento Community Edition.
I have an attribute setup that has several "values", one of which is "New".
This attribute was really set up to put little banners on product images - like "As Seen In..." or "25% off", etc.

Now that we have this attribute and our "New" products have that attribute defined as "New", what I would like to do is create a new category called "What's New" and list all products in that category which have the above attribute set to "New".  Is this possible?

Is this something that can be done "Custom Design" tab under the Category settings? Perhaps something in Custom Layout Update?

Many thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

In you product collection you could do something like

```
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('attribute_name', 'New');
```

Read more @

[Listing products by attribute](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/listing-products-by-attribute/)

[Magento - Retrieve products with a specific attribute value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1332742/magento-retrieve-products-with-a-specific-attribute-value)