# Magento Display Products On Custom Page By Atribute

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce

I am looking to have a custom CMS page with a header and text and then below it list products that have a certain custom attribute like for example color only display black products on certain page.

Is this possible

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1332742/magento-retrieve-products-with-a-specific-attribute-value

Comment: When i did a search that didnt come up but thanks that helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May I suggest using my extension?

Available on [MagentoConnect](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/custom-listings-7646.html) or [GitHub](https://github.com/openstream/CustomListing).

More info in this article: [Magento Extension to List Bestsellers, Specials, All Products or Products by Specific Attribute](http://www.openstream.ch/developer-blog/magento-extension-to-list-bestsellers-specials-all-products-or-products-by-specific-attribute/)

Answer (score 0):

I've described a small howto regarding to this question in my article:

http://www.atwix.com/magento/products-list-cms/