# Magento List products within a price range

Tags: magento, search

I'm looking to add a few 'quick links' to my store's front page, eg. "Under £10", "Under £20", etc.

Is there any easy way I can do this?

If it's going to involve code, then can anyone give me a few pointers to the best way of doing this?

Comment: You can filter you product collection as described here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1332742/magento-retrieve-products-with-a-specific-attribute-value)

Comment: Thanks, I'll read and digest.  Looks like a pretty comprehensive article but seems like the answer to, "is there an easy way", is "no"!

Comment: I can see how to build a collection containing the items I want but how do I use this collection to display content on a page?  Sorry if this should be obvious but there's stall an awful lot about Magento I don't know!

Comment: I found a way of doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact what I ended up doing was using a link to the advanced search, i.e.

```
<a href='catalogsearch/advanced/result/?price[from]=10&price[to]=20'>
```

then the results get displayed in the advanced search results window.