# Filter a specify category in magento based on attribute

Tags: magento, filter, attributes, categories

i have a category named "special deals", what i need to do is: when user open this category, the sql returns all products from all categories that have a attribute "special".

I'm starting with magento, so my knowledge is more frontend, so thank you very much if you can help me.

Comment: Either assign products to "special deals" or filter products based or "special" attribute. Why you need both then?

Comment: independent of the attribute name, I need to know how to modify the query for this category specifically.

Answer (score 0):

You can have it as follows,

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
->getCollection()
->addAttributeToFilter('attribute_code', 'attribute_value');
```

You can find the more information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1332742/magento-retrieve-products-with-a-specific-attribute-value) and [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/5838/get-product-collection-from-a-category-id)