# Get specific attributes values with link to all products having that value

Tags: php, magento-1.9

How can I get specific attribute's values in Magento with an hyperlink to a page that shows all the products that have that particular value?

Comment: What you have tried?

Comment: i have tried Alan storm's answer from this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1332742/magento-retrieve-products-with-a-specific-attribute-value)
and it gave me this Error : **Fatal error: Call to a member function getBackend() on boolean in C:\xampp\htdocs\magento-mirror-magento-1.9\app\code\core\Mage\Eav\Model\Entity\Abstract.php on line 816**

Comment: Then whats the issue you are facing? Where is your code?

Comment: this is my code: 
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('color');  


foreach ($collection as $product) {
    //var_dump($product);
    var_dump($product->getData());
}